# The equidistant set of a closed set 3

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $F$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $m\geq2$. For $r>0$, let $F_r$ be the set of points $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that dist($x,F)=r$ (distance between $x$ and $F$). Suppose there exists $r_0>0$ such that $F_{r}$ has no bounded components for all $0<r<r_0$. Can we say that $$\bigcup_{0<r<r_0}F_r$$ has no bounded components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\underset{0<r<r_0}\bigcup F_r$ has a bounded component $C$. Then there exists $x\in C$; and there exists $r\in(0,r_0)$ such that $x\in F_r$. And the component of $F_r$ that contains $x$ is a subset of $C$, and is therefore bounded $-$ contradiction.

Therefore $\underset{0<r<r_0}\bigcup F_r$ has no bounded components.